# why Span element baseline has changed after updating chrome browser to version starts from 108

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

After updating to chrome Version `108.0.5359.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)`
from `107.0.5304.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)` The `span` element got severely affected. **It just changed it's baseline when multiple span were place one top of other.**

**Expected beaviour: Span should grow on top-wards(v-107) not on bottom-wards(v-108) direction.**

**in version 107.0.5304.87 of chrome**
[image]

**in version 108.0.5359.94 of chrome**
[image]

**Uploaded the code and it give any of the result as shown in above 2 images based on your chrome version.**

```html
<html>

<body>
        <div dir="auto" style="line-height: 2.5; text-align: left;">
                <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="28" style="white-space: break-spaces;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="28_39_96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" data-start_offset="28" data-end="39" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">consectetur <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 88px; height: 23px; background: rgb(255, 0, 199); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Noun" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 0, 199); max-width: 88px; min-width: 88px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Noun</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span data-start_offset="39" data-end="57" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> adipiscing elit. </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="57_61_9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" data-start_offset="57" data-end="61" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">Cras <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 33px; height: 23px; background: rgb(97, 0, 255); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
        
        
        <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="28" style="white-space: break-spaces;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="28_39_96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" data-start_offset="28" data-end="39" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">consectetur <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 88px; height: 23px; background: rgb(255, 0, 199); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Noun" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 0, 199); max-width: 88px; min-width: 88px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Noun</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span data-start_offset="39" data-end="57" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> adipiscing elit. </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="57_61_9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" data-start_offset="57" data-end="61" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">Cras <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 33px; height: 23px; background: rgb(97, 0, 255); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
        
        
        
        <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="28" style="white-space: break-spaces;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="28_39_96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" data-start_offset="28" data-end="39" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">consectetur <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 88px; height: 23px; background: rgb(255, 0, 199); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Noun" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 0, 199); max-width: 88px; min-width: 88px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Noun</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span data-start_offset="39" data-end="57" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> adipiscing elit. </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="57_61_9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" data-start_offset="57" data-end="61" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">Cras <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 33px; height: 23px; background: rgb(97, 0, 255); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
        
        
        
        <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="28" style="white-space: break-spaces;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="28_39_96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" data-start_offset="28" data-end="39" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">consectetur <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 88px; height: 23px; background: rgb(255, 0, 199); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Noun" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 0, 199); max-width: 88px; min-width: 88px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Noun</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span data-start_offset="39" data-end="57" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> adipiscing elit. </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="57_61_9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" data-start_offset="57" data-end="61" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">Cras <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 33px; height: 23px; background: rgb(97, 0, 255); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
        
        
        
        <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="28" style="white-space: break-spaces;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="28_39_96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" data-start_offset="28" data-end="39" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">consectetur <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 88px; height: 23px; background: rgb(255, 0, 199); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Noun" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 0, 199); max-width: 88px; min-width: 88px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Noun</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span data-start_offset="39" data-end="57" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> adipiscing elit. </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="57_61_9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" data-start_offset="57" data-end="61" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">Cras <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 33px; height: 23px; background: rgb(97, 0, 255); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How to get old behaviour in new updated google chrome version?

Comment: The then why not just handle the outer div like that: <div dir="auto" style="display: flex; align-items: flex-end; line-height: 2.5; text-align: left;">

Comment: Just to note I too see this altered behavior on 108. Also just to note that strictly a mark element should not have a div as content - though I don't think that accounts for the problem you are seeing.

Comment: @AHaworth I also tried with span and other elements the issue is same. I want to know how browser handling this So I'll reverse the behaviour. for that any help?

Comment: @dbonev The thing is just to make it ease I added only 4 spans in a code. If u just copy paste it 5 times then multi lines will come. Then your logic will totally fail. Please try it. I only updated the code u can copy.

Comment: Please have a look at the edited code example below inside the answer. This is working inside my browser. Pleas test it at yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change comes from [this CL](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/4293e3e1f9e70f6b38556cbcd6caa6f50bc092bf), which links to the [issue 885175](https://crbug.com/885175).
From that issue we can see that Chrome did implement the [`align-self: last baseline`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/#valdef-justify-self-last-baseline) value.

---

*Note: I kind of discover this value and I'm not 100% confident on what exactly happened before, happens now, or, should happen. If one wants to correct me, please do so.*

---

The default value for `align-self` apparently becomes `first baseline` in their new implementation. I'm not sure what it was before (or what it is in other UAs), computing the [value `auto`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/#valdef-align-self-auto) is bit of a rabbit hole for me, but it apparently had the same behavior as `last baseline`, and at least not the same as current Chrome's `first baseline`.

So, to get the same behavior in Chrome >= 108 than in other UAs and previous Chromes, you can force the `align-self` value of your inner flex containers (basically your `<mark>` elements) to be `last baseline`.

Here is a minimal-repro with the fix:

```css
.parent-flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
/*
  For the demo we apply the fix only when the input is checked.
  You would obviously add it in your .column rule,
  or in OP's case on their <mark> elements
*/
:checked ~ * .column {
  align-self: last baseline;
}
```

```html
<label for=inp>Apply the fix</label><input type=checkbox id=inp><br><br>

<span>Inline</span>
<span class="parent-flex">
  <span class="column">
    <span>row</span>
    <span>row</span>
    <span>row</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

And OP's very not minimal code with the fix:

```css
mark { align-self: last baseline }
```

```html
        <div dir="auto" style="line-height: 2.5; text-align: left;">
                <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="28" style="white-space: break-spaces;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="28_39_96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" data-start_offset="28" data-end="39" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">consectetur <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 88px; height: 23px; background: rgb(255, 0, 199); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Noun" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 0, 199); max-width: 88px; min-width: 88px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Noun</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span data-start_offset="39" data-end="57" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> adipiscing elit. </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="57_61_9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" data-start_offset="57" data-end="61" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">Cras <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 33px; height: 23px; background: rgb(97, 0, 255); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
        
        
        <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="28" style="white-space: break-spaces;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="28_39_96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" data-start_offset="28" data-end="39" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">consectetur <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 88px; height: 23px; background: rgb(255, 0, 199); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Noun" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 0, 199); max-width: 88px; min-width: 88px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Noun</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span data-start_offset="39" data-end="57" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> adipiscing elit. </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="57_61_9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" data-start_offset="57" data-end="61" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">Cras <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 33px; height: 23px; background: rgb(97, 0, 255); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
        
        
        
        <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="28" style="white-space: break-spaces;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="28_39_96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" data-start_offset="28" data-end="39" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">consectetur <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 88px; height: 23px; background: rgb(255, 0, 199); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Noun" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 0, 199); max-width: 88px; min-width: 88px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Noun</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span data-start_offset="39" data-end="57" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> adipiscing elit. </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="57_61_9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" data-start_offset="57" data-end="61" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">Cras <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 33px; height: 23px; background: rgb(97, 0, 255); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
        
        
        
        <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="28" style="white-space: break-spaces;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="28_39_96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" data-start_offset="28" data-end="39" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">consectetur <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 88px; height: 23px; background: rgb(255, 0, 199); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Noun" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 0, 199); max-width: 88px; min-width: 88px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Noun</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span data-start_offset="39" data-end="57" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> adipiscing elit. </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="57_61_9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" data-start_offset="57" data-end="61" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">Cras <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 33px; height: 23px; background: rgb(97, 0, 255); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
        
        
        
        <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="28" style="white-space: break-spaces;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="28_39_96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" data-start_offset="28" data-end="39" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">consectetur <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 88px; height: 23px; background: rgb(255, 0, 199); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Noun" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 0, 199); max-width: 88px; min-width: 88px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Noun</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span data-start_offset="39" data-end="57" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> adipiscing elit. </span>
                <span>
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="57_61_9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" data-start_offset="57" data-end="61" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">Cras <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 33px; height: 23px; background: rgb(97, 0, 255); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html><head></head><body>
        <div dir="auto" style="line-height: 2.5;text-align: left;display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;">
    
                <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="28" style="white-space: break-spaces;align-self: flex-end;line-height: 1.5;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>
                <span style="
    align-self: flex-end;
">
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="28_39_96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" data-start_offset="28" data-end="39" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);background: rgb(255, 255, 255);position: relative;padding: 0px;cursor: default;display: flex;flex-direction: column-reverse;opacity: 0.9;line-height: 1.5em;">consectetur <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 88px;height: 23px;background: rgb(255, 0, 199);position: absolute;z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Noun" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 0, 199); max-width: 88px; min-width: 88px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Noun</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span data-start_offset="39" data-end="57" style="white-space: break-spaces;align-self: flex-end;line-height: 1.5;"> adipiscing elit. </span>
                <span style="
    align-self: flex-end;
">
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="57_61_9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" data-start_offset="57" data-end="61" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">Cras <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 33px; height: 23px; background: rgb(97, 0, 255); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
        
        
        <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="28" style="white-space: break-spaces;align-self: flex-end;line-height: 1.5;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>
                <span style="
    align-self: flex-end;
">
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="28_39_96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" data-start_offset="28" data-end="39" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">consectetur <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 88px; height: 23px; background: rgb(255, 0, 199); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Noun" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 0, 199); max-width: 88px; min-width: 88px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Noun</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span data-start_offset="39" data-end="57" style="white-space: break-spaces;align-self: flex-end;line-height: 1.5;"> adipiscing elit. </span>
                <span style="
    align-self: flex-end;
">
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="57_61_9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" data-start_offset="57" data-end="61" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">Cras <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 33px; height: 23px; background: rgb(97, 0, 255); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
        
        
        
        <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="28" style="white-space: break-spaces;align-self: flex-end;line-height: 1.5;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>
                <span style="
    align-self: flex-end;
">
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="28_39_96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" data-start_offset="28" data-end="39" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">consectetur <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 88px; height: 23px; background: rgb(255, 0, 199); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Noun" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 0, 199); max-width: 88px; min-width: 88px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Noun</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span data-start_offset="39" data-end="57" style="white-space: break-spaces;align-self: flex-end;line-height: 1.5;"> adipiscing elit. </span>
                <span style="
    align-content: flex-end;
">
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="57_61_9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" data-start_offset="57" data-end="61" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">Cras <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 33px; height: 23px; background: rgb(97, 0, 255); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
        
        
        
        <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="28" style="white-space: break-spaces;align-self: flex-end;line-height: 1.5;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>
                <span style="
    align-self: flex-end;
">
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="28_39_96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" data-start_offset="28" data-end="39" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">consectetur <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 88px; height: 23px; background: rgb(255, 0, 199); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Noun" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 0, 199); max-width: 88px; min-width: 88px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Noun</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span data-start_offset="39" data-end="57" style="white-space: break-spaces;align-self: flex-end;line-height: 1.5;"> adipiscing elit. </span>
                <span style="
    align-self: flex-end;
">
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="57_61_9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" data-start_offset="57" data-end="61" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">Cras <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 33px; height: 23px; background: rgb(97, 0, 255); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
        
        
        
        <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="28" style="white-space: break-spaces;align-self: flex-end;line-height: 1.5;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>
                <span style="
    align-self: flex-end;
">
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="28_39_96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" data-start_offset="28" data-end="39" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">consectetur <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 88px; height: 23px; background: rgb(255, 0, 199); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Noun" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="96d6a5ea-a48a-447e-9312-cac338d30c4a" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 0, 199); max-width: 88px; min-width: 88px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Noun</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span data-start_offset="39" data-end="57" style="white-space: break-spaces;align-self: flex-end;line-height: 1.5;"> adipiscing elit. </span>
                <span style="
    align-content: flex-end;
">
                    <span style="display: inline-flex; align-items: flex-end; position: relative;">
                        <mark id="57_61_9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" data-start_offset="57" data-end="61" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; padding: 0px; cursor: default; display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; opacity: 0.9; line-height: 1.5em;">Cras <div style="position: absolute; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24); height: 23px; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
                            <div style="min-width: 33px; height: 23px; background: rgb(97, 0, 255); position: absolute; z-index: -2;"></div>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                            <span title="Name" class="" style="display: flex; min-height: 1.2em;">
                                <span id="9137407f-934d-4d0a-95fe-5c5205edf092" class="renderLabel" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(97, 0, 255); max-width: 33px; min-width: 33px; margin-left: 0px; flex: 1 1 0%;">Name</span>
                            </span>
                        </mark>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>


</body></html>
```

The changes are:

- display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; - to the wrapping div
- align-self: flex-end; - to the content that should stay on the bottom
- line-height: 1.5em; - to the items that should be properly aligned to the baseline

Comment: What are the changes this answer made that made it work?

Comment: The changes are: display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap; - to the wrapping div. align-self: flex-end; - to the content that should stay on the bottom. line-height: 1.5em; - to the items that should be properly aligned to the baseline

Comment: Include this info in your answer.

Comment: Info changes are applied